# Jersey Support is Jersey 2.35 not Jersey 3.x

Tags: websocket, jersey, helidon

I have a server I built a few years ago which provides both REST endpoints and websocket.
It packages as a jar file (as opposed to war) with an embedded Jetty server.  Rest is provided by Jersey(2.26).  Jersey and JEE Websocket are each ContextHandlers configured into Jetty.  The server was built on Java 8.

I want to update the server.  My main goals of the update is move to Java 17 and from JEE->Jakarta.
I just found Helidon and thought it to be the perfect solution, particularly since it even has an example of a server that combines REST and websocket.

As I started working with Helidon I found to my disappointment that helidon-webserver-jersey pulls in Jersey2.35 (JEE) not Jersey3.x (Jakarta).

I know that Jersey is doing parallel development in 2.x and 3.x, but I'm still surprised that something as new as Helidon connects to 2.x not 3.x.

I'm curious what the reasoning was behind that decision and if there are plans in the near future to move to Jersey3.x

I haven't started on the websocket piece yet, but I'm guessing its JEE not Jarkata as well.  Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Jersey 3.x as well as the full "jakartification" of Helidon will come with version 3.x.
3.0.0-M1 is already available: https://medium.com/helidon/helidon-3-0-0-m1-release-7dad655cd469

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Alexandrov.  Exactly what I needed.  Server is working now with Helidon 3.0.0-M1, Jersey 3.x (Jakarta) and Websockets.

Comment: Awesome. Full 3.0.0 coming soon :)